Angular 17+ Standalone Modules
I've used Angular before, but an earlier version. Can someone educate me on why my routes for my navbar doesn't work with my Contact Page.
Here is the link... https://github.com/Logan-0/ngPersonal
My biggest concern is Understanding why I need, Index.html and app.component.html and the components specific html. I assume I can remove one of them.
What I thought I tried; maybe I imagined it.
Redoing routes. Adding Redirects. It even worked for a while, then I touched something.
Added and removed the following tags for the components and higher level html pages; <html><head><body>
Update, This change does not work either:
 ```<li class="nav-item home" id='nav-links'>
        <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item about" id='nav-links'>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item contact" id='nav-links'>
        <a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item project" id='nav-links'>
        <a [routerLink]="['/projects']">Projects</a>
    </li>```


Hi, @BabyLogan could you please share the error your Angular application is encountering or the console error that is being thrown?

I wish I could. Each other page link displays correctly, and when you inspect the page, the html from the routerOutlet displays as it should.
When I click the "Contact" button the entire html dissapears. It gets removed instead of replaced with the component information.
So tldr; When I click the specific nav button for "contact" the corresponding html disappears.

Because the path should starting from "/"
<li class="nav-item about" id='nav-links'>
  <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
</li>


Second update: extended url in address bar does not change from splash page -> on nav click -> remains at localhost:4200/

Final update: Solved!
Had nothing to do with routing.
In appConfig.ts
Under "providers" array
Needed to add "provideHttpClient()"
Component used and Api Service Call and missing the provider denied the module from loading entirely
